# Set up a different wait time for a specific line in the code

Tags: java, mobile, automation, appium, wait

Im automating a load money operation on android using appium, java, JUnit and as a maven project. And in order to handle timeout exception, i have a wait capacity like this:

`wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);`

And i usually write the lines like this:
`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("login_btn"))).click();`

This approach works just fine except for one line. I want my code to wait around 60 seconds for a specific line. Because it takes about 60 seconds for that page to load.

```
    public void loadMoney() {

        successfulLogIn();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("loadBtn"))).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("currencyEur"))).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("activityLoadMoney_textView_cardLastFourDigit"))).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("rowYourCards_card_container"))).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("moneyInputLayout_editText_mainCurrencyAmount"))).sendKeys(loadMoneyAmount);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("activityLoadMoney_textView_loadMoney"))).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("successtext")));
        MobileElement result = driver.findElement(By.id("successtext"));
        Assert.assertEquals((result.getText()), "Successfully sent!");
    }
```

In the code above, I want my code to wait around 60 seconds for this line

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("successtext")));`

because it takes about 60 seconds for this text to show up. And as i mentioned above, my wait time is set to 15 seconds. Therefore im getting TimeoutException.. I dont wanna change the whole wait time to 60 seconds because it would take too much time for other methods. I just want my code to wait for 60 seconds specifically for this line only. How can i do that? Do i need to write a new method for that? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("activityLoadMoney_textView_loadMoney"))).click();

wait.wait(60);  // you need to add this line

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("successtext")))
```

By this way you to do not create an another object of `WebDriverWait`

Note: you again need to change wait time further to 10 if next element waiting for 10 seconds only as after `wait.wait(60);` the driver wait time set to 60 not 10 anymore

Comment: Tried your solution and added wait.wait(60); before the aforementioned line. it underlined the second wait() and asked me to add InterruptedException to the method. I added this exception and run the test again.

This time i got IllegalMonitorStateException, and after a bit search on the net, i replaced wait.wait(60) with Thread.sleep(60000); and it worked.

So you helped me indirectly. :) although i do want to solve this with wait instead of sleep

Comment: then instead of thread create an another object of WebDriverWait as wait2 set its value to 60 use it for only successtext

Comment: As per your suggestion, i created this inside the method:

`WebDriverWait waitFor40Seconds = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);`


Then i write this for the success screen:
`waitFor40Seconds.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("successtext")));`

this gives me timeout exception, and it doesn't wait for 40 seconds, instead it waits for the default 15 seconds :/

Comment: Why 40 now when you have 60 second wait previously

Comment: i just wanted to test it to see if it would wait for 40 seconds. but it didnt. then i changed it to 60 seconds and it didnt work either.